# PHP автозагрузчик классов перестает находить класс по namespace, если имя класса задано через переменную

Tags: php

В общем, суть такова: мой автозагрузчик должен находить все классы раскиданные по разным папкам по namespace, и он находит. Проблемы начинаются когда я пытаюсь задать имя класса через переменную, вот например этот вариант работает, он находит класс Articles и ищет его в пути cnt\Articles.php:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    require $className.'.php';
});

include("config/cfg.php");

use classes\Router, cnt\Articles;

$router = new Router($cfg["router"], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$route = $router->getClassAndMethod();

$obj = new Articles();
$obj->actionIndex();
```

Вот это не рабочий вариант , он не находит класс Articles и ищет его в пути Articles.php, хотя $route['class'] === Articles, он почему-то через namespace искать не хочет:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    require $className.'.php';
});

include("config/cfg.php");

use classes\Router, cnt\Articles;

$router = new Router($cfg["router"], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$route = $router->getClassAndMethod();

$obj = new $route['class']();
$obj->$route['function']($route["parameters"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае вы определяете полный `namespace` класса `Articles` через ключевое слово `use`, в итоге метод `spl_autoload_register()` принимает в переменную `$className`: **app\controllers\Arciles**, и потом подключает файл по пути `../www/app/controllers/Article.php`, через `require_once`.

```php
use app\controllers\Arciles;

$article = new Articles();
```

Во втором случае вы создаете экземпляр класса `Articles` "анонимно", заранее не зная какой путь указать в `use ...`, потому что в переменной `$route['class']` может содержаться абсолютно любое значение. Для того чтобы подключить класс "анонимно", вы должны указать `namespace` полностью:

```php
$class = 'app\\controllers\\' . ucwords($route['class']); //  'app\\controllers\\Articles'

$obj = new $class();
$obj->{$route['function']}($route["parameters"]);
```